# Double negation in Russian

Tags: перевод

> Es gibt **nichts**, das ich mir **nicht** leisten könnte!

```
= There's nothing I can't afford!
```

I just noticed this original German sentence with a double negative construction is for some reason translated (by a professional Russian translator, no less) into something as straightforward as:

> Я все могу купить!

Which makes me wonder if the use of double negation somehow doesn't sound idiomatic in Russian in an instance like this?

Comment: “Нет ничего невозможного” sounds natural and idiomatic, for example.

Comment: "Нет ничего, чего/что я бы себе не мог позволить", sounds acceptable, but to be fair, somewhat clumsy, and there's a little problem of tautology in *ничего - чего* if we opt-in for this variant

Comment: in English a more precise rendering would be *"... i couldn't/wouldn't be able to afford"*

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка Actually, "There is nothing I *can't* do" without the conditional is how you say it in English, not "There is nothing I *couldn't* do".

Comment: @Alone-zee, OK you may be are right, there's a handful of examples in Google, so these are perhaps mistakes, in Russian the subjunctive mood isn't absolutely necessary, but it sounds better

Comment: Isn't it a subject of that probability gradations expressed via tenses? can/could/had could? Like "Wish you are/were/had been here" ?

Comment: I think the translator had more trouble with the word afford than with the double negative.

Answer (score 4):

There's the "нет ничего, чего (я/он/...) не мог бы (сделать/...)" construction, which may, or in some cases (i.e. with some verbs) may not sound natural.

In your case the translation by that template would be "нет ничего, чего я купить бы не смог (or: чего я не смог бы купить)". To my taste, such construction in general sounds just a little bit dramatic, maybe, not just neutrally narrative, but it sounds all right.

UPDATE: There's also the variant "нет ничего, *что* (я/он/...) не мог бы (сделать/...)", but I don't remember whether it's considered 100% literary.

Comment: * не**т** ничего

Answer (score -3):

You could translate this as:

> Нет `того`, что я не мог бы себе позволить!

Keeping closer to the original German wording,

> `И несть того, в чём я б себе бы не позволил!` (Начальное "И" добавлено для поддержки темпа в рифмованном слоге; "несть" - для придания архаичности)